# mockk function with Flow inconsistence

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, kotlin-flow, mockk

I am writing an Android Unit Test for a ViewModel.
I am mocking a flow like this:

```
coEvery { showRepository.currentShow() } returns flowOf(
   ShowWithRelations(
      localShow.show,
      localShow.actions,
      localShow.organisers,
      localShow.featuredUsers
   )
)
```

Then, inside the viewModel, I have this line
`showRepository.currentShow().filterNotNull().first()`
which throws an Exception for not having any element.

The thing is, if I debug the test, and stop before calling the function of the ViewModel that runs the above line, the same code yields the correct value.

Any idea?
The line is launched inside a `scope.launch {}` but others mocked functions are as well, and they all work fine.
The `scope` is injected in the ViewModel and it is a `TestScope(UnconfinedTestDispatcher())`